# Cyanobacteria and the ratio of Iron to Phosphorous

Tags: bacteriology, photosynthesis

In listening to a recorded lecture that touched on the Great Oxidation Event, a casual remark was made to the effect that the shifting of the Earth's constituents to more availability of phosphorous relative to iron was a key factor in the ability of cyanobacteria to produce oxygen.

[Although it was primarily a geology lecture, it did not mention what caused that shift.]

How would this change (if one could go so far) prime the pump for the GOE?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2020.541558/full

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thanks. Hardly "In"!